# Javascript setInterval/setTimeout not working when browser tab not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, focus

So I'm modifying a Highcharts piechart trying to execute the following:

```
function updateAngle( lastAngle ) {
    if ($("#container").highcharts() != null && $("#container").highcharts() != undefined) {
        var currentAngle = lastAngle;
        var destinationAngle = getAngle();
        if (currentAngle != destinationAngle) {
            currentAngle += 1;
            if (currentAngle > destinationAngle) {
                currentAngle = destinationAngle;
            }
            $("#container").highcharts().get('Series').update({
                endAngle: currentAngle
            });
            setTimeout(updateAngle, 1, currentAngle);
        }
    }
}
```

After each interation I'm adding 1 to the previous angle, now I've read that setInterval/setTimeout doesn't work with browsers when tabbed out due to it not requesting animation. I've read that ".queue" is a function that can work for me, but I'm unsure how to convert my setTimeout method to using .queue.

Answer (score 1):

Timeouts are clamped to firing no more often than once per second (1000 ms) in inactive tabs, but they still fire. You won't have any issue with your code.

Comment: But once per 1000ms is WAY to slow considering this is displaying data that may not need to be displayed any longer by the time they've re-focused.

Comment: When you switch between tabs, you can call clearInterval() to reset setInterval. When focus, create new setInterval().